# Can I run a C# game on asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xna

I have searched the web for the answer to this; "Is it possible to launch a game from an asp.net core web site/server?".

I don't know if the XNA framework will work with this new framework, or is there any alternative?

I would really like to not write my games in javascript, but prefer c#, and hoped that there would be a solution like a java applet, but for c#.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but since ASP.NET Core is built ground-up from scratch to work cross-platform, it won't be compatible with XNA, at least as for now.

Comment: C# .NET Core code runs on the server, so any rendering/state updates are subject to latency - not the best for a game. You want as much rendering happening on your client as possible, so javascript game libraries are the way to go.FYI XNA has also been discontinued since 2013.

Comment: Microsoft have tried to bring C# code into a browser.. (silverlight) It wasn't a great success.

Comment: @JoãoLourenço but isn't javascript games hackable?

I wanted to make an arcade, and it's not fun, if the user can hack their own score :)

Comment: @Musen everything is hackable. You just need to have the defensive logic in your server-side API. The javascript side should be as thin as it can.

Comment: You can go with the Unity engine and publish it to the web.

Comment: @Musen Anything is hackable irrespective of whether it is a game; whether it is c# or not.  Lots of "trainers" for AAA Windows games

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET Core is a web framework that enables you to develop web applications. It is running on the server (multiplattform). For Client side code ASP.NET Core can work in conjunction with multiple client frameworks (plain javascript, AngualarJS, ...). But it does not give you the ability to develop code in C# that is executed in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, it is not possible to do so with the current tools the Net framework provides.

But you can use [Unity](https://unity3d.com/), which is a game engine that allows you to write game in a couple of languages, c# is one of those.

The latest version allows you to create and [publish a game using the web GL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html) option which will run on a browser with no additional plug ins.

You probably want to take a look at that.